# Adjective after noun?

Tags: adjectives, nouns

I'm currently struggling with a minor grammatical issue and would love to get your opinion.

Sometimes an adjective is placed after the noun. Is there a specific rule when this is okay?

E.g., "using the selected methods..." vs. "using the methods selected..."?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the following two sentences:

*"Using the selected methods should result in success."*
*"Using the methods selected by our committee should result in success."*

In the first sentence **selected** is acting as a simple *adjective* modifying the noun **methods.**

In the second sentence **selected** introduces an *adjectival phrase* modifying the noun.

Comment: I don't think the second situation shows an adjectival phrase. *Selected* is acting as the past participle in a verb phrase, which would explain why we'd need the *by*. You can see this because "that were" can be added back into the second sentence while retaining the exact same meaning. The sentence in this case would be: "Using the methods that were selected by our committee should result in success."

Answer (score 0):

```
From the highlighted phrases, pick the one that is ungrammatical.       
From the phrases highlighted, pick the one that is ungrammatical.
```

They're pretty much interchangeable. The second form gives you the ability to tack on a modifying phrase:

From the phrases highlighted in bold, pick the one....

**Bill sat quietly.**

**Bill was less talkative than usual.**

**Bill sat as quiet like a mouse.**

However, "highlighted in bold" is an elliptical form of "that are highlighted in bold". But that's neither here nor there.

Comment: "Billy sat as quiet like a mouse" is incorrect. Either set as quiet as a mouse or sat quiet, like a mouse.